# How to add files to build "pocketsphinx" in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, codeblocks, pocketsphinx

I can compile the sample `continuous.c` file by this command inside Ubuntu terminal:

```
gcc -o continuous continuous.c     -DMODELDIR=\"`pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx`\"     `pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase`
```

But if I want to build it inside `codeblocks` how should I do it?

Comment: Why do you need to do it Code::Blocks, since you've already done it in this much simpler way?

Comment: Because sometimes I get `segmentation fault(core dumped)` errors and it's easy to debug it on codeblocks!

Comment: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/FAQ-Compiling_(general)#Q:_I_would_like_to_compile_a_project_using_some_non-standard_libraries._How_can_I_indicate_to_CodeBlocks_that_these_libraries_and_include_files_exist.3F